# django-tables2 column right justify

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using `django-tables2` to display a table containing an integer value and would like to know how to right-justify the column.

Is there a parameter/attr in the `tables.py`?

Here's what's displaying:

[image: integer column]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `td` and `th` elements in the generated html will have the column name as a class attribute. That way you can easily refer to a column in your CSS.

Additionally, you can provide attributes for `th`, `td` cell elements by passing a keyword argument `attrs` to the definition of the `Column` as described in the [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html#column-attributes):

```
class SimpleTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(
        attrs={
            "th": {"id": "foo"},
            "td": {"align": "right"}
        }
    )
```

The`th` and `td` elements of this column will look like:

```
<th id="foo" class="name"> ... </th>
<td align="right" class="name"> ... </td>
```

Comment: This worked for me: `'td':{'style':'text-align: right;'}`.

Comment: for me a combination of both worked: ``attrs={'th': {'style':'text-align: right;'}, 'td': {'align': 'right'}}``